# How can formatting asp:FileUpload control with bootstrap?

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, file-upload

I want change display `<asp:FileUpload>` control's with bootstrap. Here is the what I want for display: [file input style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqBme.png)

I have searched this topic for 2 days, and I found these articles:

- http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html
  (I can't write others because of my reputation)

And more, but -sorry for this- I am not able to use in my codes.

I can change input tag's display but then when I delete input tag and write there `<asp:FileUpload>` it doesn't work. Thank for your answers.

Comment: can you not add a `Css`, or `Class` attribute to the `<asp:FileUpload>` tag?

Comment: @mmcrae Yes I can but when I add a CssClass property, just change backgroud color.

Comment: You can set whatever styles (beyond background-color) you want by specifying what CssClass it uses (as long as the CssClass defines the rules you need). If you need to add other DOM elements for the look/and feel, add that to the markup.

Comment: @mmcrae thanks for your answer, but i couldn't tell well :) When I use CssClass property, it can change only bg color, 
doesn't apply to others.